# How to load a large local image (works on simulator, not test device)?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage

I'm currently trying to load a map image which is a large(16mb) .jpg file inside a scrollView so you can zoom in and out.

When I launch the app inside the simulator everything runs fine and smooth. However once I run it on my test device (iPod 4.1, iOS 6.0) the app shows the launch image and then it crashes with no error messages at all.

This is how the code currently looks like.

```
myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"map.jpg"]];

myScrollView=[[UIScrollView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15,120,290,365)];
myScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator=YES;
myScrollView.scrollEnabled=YES;
myScrollView.maximumZoomScale = 10.0;
myScrollView.minimumZoomScale = [myScrollView frame].size.width / myImage.frame.size.width;
myScrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
myScrollView.bounces = NO;

myScrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
myScrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;

[self.view addSubview:whiteFrame];
[self.view addSubview:myScrollView];

myScrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(myImage.frame.size.width,myImage.frame.size.height);
myScrollView.delegate = self;
myScrollView.zoomScale = [myScrollView frame].size.width / myImage.frame.size.width;

[myScrollView addSubview:myImage];
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I found this in the docs

If you have a very large image, or are loading image data over the web, you may want to create an incremental image source so that you can draw the image data as you accumulate it. You need to perform the following tasks to load an image incrementally from a CFData object:

1. Create the CFData object for accumulating the image data.
2. Create an incremental image source by calling the function CGImageSourceCreateIncremental.
3. Add image data to the CFData object.
4. Call the function CGImageSourceUpdateData, passing the CFData object and a Boolean value (bool data type) that specifies whether the data parameter contains the entire image, or just partial image data. In any case, the data parameter must contain all the image file data accumulated up to that point.
5. If you have accumulated enough image data, create an image by calling CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex, draw the partial image, and then release it.
6. Check to see if you have all the data for an image by calling the function CGImageSourceGetStatusAtIndex. If the image is complete, this function returns kCGImageStatusComplete. If the image is not complete, repeat steps 3 and 4 until it is.
7. Release the incremental image source.

Does anyone know about a sample code for that ?

Answer (score 1):

A 16mb jpg is going to take a pretty decent chunk of RAM when uncompressed. Your app is probably crashing because it is using too much memory. You can check this by reproducing the crash and checking the device's console log in the Xcode organizer.

You will need to either:

1. Reduce the dimensions of the image as much as your design will permit to greatly reduce memory usage. For example, there's no reason to have a 16mb jpg if it will never be shown at full-resolution.
2. Chop the image up into tiles and only load the tiles currently displayed on the screen and the surrounding areas. Then load additional tiles as the user scrolls around. This is how maps apps are able to display extremely large images without running out of RAM.

Remember to also test your app on the supported device with the lowest amount of RAM. These devices will probably kill your app sooner than the newest devices.

Comment: Regardless of byte size (16MB, etc.), I wonder what happens regarding pixel size. I know there is a limit for OpenGL texture sizes on each GPU (I believe it is 4096 x 4096 on latest iPhone, but not sure), but perhaps UIKit/CoreGraphics handle this for you by internally tiling large images into multiple textures. Does anyone know?

Answer (score 1):

At 16 MB, the image is too big for your iPod to handle. The app is crashing because it's loading the image directly, and asking for too much memory and the system has had to kill it.

You should create a smaller version of your image, in terms of both canvas size and image quality, for your app.

You could also [incrementally load the image](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/graphicsimaging/conceptual/ImageIOGuide/imageio_source/ikpg_source.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005462-CH218-DontLinkElementID_7) instead.

When you're testing on the simulator, it has full access to the gobs of memory on your computer. Way more than the 256MB available to your iPod 4 (there isn't such thing as an iPod 4.1).

Comment: Image quality has no bearing on the size of the decompressed image in RAM.

Comment: @fzwo Yes, and there's no sense having a super-high-definition picture on a 480x320 screen, in an even smaller scroll view

Comment: Canvas size matters; image quality, as you write in your answer, does not.

Comment: @fzwo I don't understand your point. Quality level affects the size of the file, and since there's no sense having a higher quality level than the device is capable of presenting, why not reduce the quality? It is a good idea to reduce the size of assets whenever possible because it reduces the size of the app (or the amount of time it takes to transfer the file).

Comment: It reduces fils size, and thus app size (and also possibly decompression time, since decompression is probably faster than reading a large uncompressed file from flash memory), but it has no bearing at all on RAM footprint. All displayed images reside in RAM as uncompressed bitmaps.

Comment: @fzwo I've already agreed with you about that. I'm still not sure what your point is, so I won't engage any further.

Comment: My point was merely that reducing file quality by increasing file compression has nothing to do with the original question and might lead the asker astray. It can be a viable strategy to reduce app file size and/or improve load times (though the latter must be measured on device, and may differ across different devices and compression formats and factors).

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at CATiledLayer
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CATiledLayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html

There is also an example Apple project using it
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/PhotoScroller/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010080

Good luck

Comment: Didn't even know that existed. Great find, I might have to use it in a project.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are not loading this image on app launch. Application launch should be as light as possible. If launch time is more than 20 secs then iOS kills the app on its own. On simulator resources are much bigger and you may not see the similar behavior as that with device. You may also want to use the lazy loading technique to load lighter image first and then load heavy image only when needed while zooming, panning etc.

Having said that, one imortant aspect of [UIImage imageNamed] is that it caches all images loaded in that way and they never get unloaded, even if you dealloc the UIImage that was created! This is good in some circumstances (e.g. smallish images in UITableView cells), but bad in others (e.g. large images).

The solution is to use [UIImage imageWithData] which does not do this caching and which unloads the data when the UIImage is dealloc'd.

Another solution to this problem consists of either loading scaled version of the image (*1) or you have option to display it in full resolution with help of CATiledLayer(*2).

1. [UIImage imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:];
2. [CATiledLayer example](http://bill.dudney.net/roller/objc/entry/catiledlayer_example)

Comment: You talk about " The lazy loading technique", do you know about any samples for that ?